# Strange behaviour when adding doubles

Tags: c++, visual-studio, double

I am working on a Direct3D project and in my code there is a function which takes a double as a parameter, this double represents the time since the last frame, the idea was to sum this time with another double which represents the angle of rotation of a cube, and then store the new value as the new angle, but after debugging I noticed that the angle (called rot in the code) starting from zero jumps in the very first frame to a value like ~79800, every time it is slightly different but has always 79 as first numbers, I really don't understand what the problem is.

Here is the run every frame:

```
double rot = 0.0f;
double seconds = 0.0;
unsigned int frames = 0;

// this is the function used to render a single frame
void RenderFrame(double time)
{
    // clear the back buffer to a deep blue
    devcon->ClearRenderTargetView(renderTarget, D3DXCOLOR(0.0f, 0.2f, 0.4f, 1.0f));
    devcon->ClearDepthStencilView(stencilView, D3D11_CLEAR_DEPTH, 1.0f, 0);

    //PROBLEM HERE
    //////
    rot += time;
    //////


    VSCBdata.transformation = XMMatrixTranspose(XMMatrixRotationX(rot) * XMMatrixRotationZ(rot) * XMMatrixTranslation(0.0f, 0.0f, 4.0f) * XMMatrixPerspectiveLH(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.5f, 10.0f));

    devcon->UpdateSubresource(VSConstantBuffer, 0, NULL, &VSCBdata, 0, 0);

    // draw the vertex buffer to the back buffer
    devcon->DrawIndexed(ARRAYSIZE(indices), 0, 0);

    VSCBdata.transformation = XMMatrixTranspose(XMMatrixRotationY(rot) * XMMatrixRotationZ(rot) * XMMatrixTranslation(0.0f, 2.0f, 6.0f) * XMMatrixPerspectiveLH(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.5f, 10.0f));

    devcon->UpdateSubresource(VSConstantBuffer, 0, NULL, &VSCBdata, 0, 0);

    // draw the vertex buffer to the back buffer
    devcon->DrawIndexed(ARRAYSIZE(indices), 0, 0);

    // do 3D rendering on the back buffer here

    // switch the back buffer and the front buffer
    swapchain->Present(0, 0);
}
```

And here is the code that calculates the time passed:

```
double frequency = 0.0;
__int64 start = 0;
__int64 lastFrame = 0;

void StartTimer()
{
    LARGE_INTEGER shish;
    QueryPerformanceFrequency(&shish);
    frequency = double(shish.QuadPart);
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&shish);
    start = shish.QuadPart;
}

double GetTime()
{
    LARGE_INTEGER time;
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&time);
    return (time.QuadPart - start) / frequency;
}

double GetFrameTime()
{
    LARGE_INTEGER time;
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&time);
    __int64 result = time.QuadPart - lastFrame;
    lastFrame = time.QuadPart;
    if (result < 0.0) result = 0.0;
    return double(result)/frequency;
}
```

Comment: What units is time in?

Comment: Please remove any code which is not needed for the problem to still occur.

Comment: Unless time is in radians, you need a conversion factor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `lastFrame` is initialised to `0` the first call to `GetFrameTime` will return the value of `QueryPerformanceCounter` in seconds.

You should either call `GetFrameTime` once at the start of your program and discard the value or initialise `lastFrame` in `StartTimer`.

Comment: I've initialized lastFrame in StartTimer as shish.QuadPart and now it works perfectly, thank you really, really much.